# Node.js/Javascript Recursive Map Reduction to remove unchanged children

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a key/value map of paths that have changed that looks like this example:

```
{
  '/A' => '/AA',
  '/A/B' => '/AA/B',
  '/A/C' => '/AA/C',
  '/A/D' => '/AA/D'
}
```

The left value is the old path, the right value is the new path.

I need to reduce this to just the paths that have changed and filter out the redundant non-changed children.  For example, if I change '/A' to '/AA' then I don't need the children, unless they have been changed, etc.

The rub is these paths can be quite deep and I need to somehow recursively end up with just what has actually changed.

3 days no luck, can't get my head around it, thanks mighty code warriors for any help :)

Comment: what is a changed path?

Comment: "*recursively end up with just what has actually changed.*" - I don't see a reason to use recursion. Or do you need to consider move chains (where an item first moves from a to b and then from b to c, equivalent to moving from a to c)?

Comment: Think in terms of files on a disk that have been renamed, that's an easy analogy.

Comment: Recursion might be the wrong approach, I'm not even sure how to tackle this.  I can do it on one level, but when the depth is unknown the logic escapes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate them and remove everything for which a matching ancestor move exists:

```js
const moves = new Map([
  ['/A', '/AA'],
  ['/A/B', '/AA/B'],
  ['/A/C', '/AA/C'],
  ['/A/D', '/AA/X'],
]);

for (const [from, to] of moves) {
  const fromParts = from.split('/');
  for (let i=1; i<fromParts.length; i++) {
    const parentFrom = fromParts.slice(0, i).join('/');
    const parentTo = moves.get(parentFrom);
    if (parentTo !== undefined) {
      const sub = '/' + fromParts.slice(i).join('/');
      if (parentTo + sub === to) {
        console.log(`Move ${from}=>${to} contained in move ${parentFrom}=>${parentTo}`);
        moves.delete(from);
      } else {
        console.log(`Source ${from} is part of ${parentFrom}, but ${sub} was moved to ${to} instead of ${parentTo + sub}`);
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(Object.fromEntries(moves));
```

If you don't like to mutate the input `moves` map, you can also just use `filter()` on an array of moves; it just needs to be able to lookup potential parent moves.

Comment: Thank you! I'm evaluating it now but this looks great :)